# Change the label position of each figure to the bottom with plot_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I would like to change the position of each label to the bottom and centered part of each figure, is it possible?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
df <- data.frame(
   x = 1:10, y1 = 1:10, y2 = (1:10)^2, y3 = (1:10)^3, y4 = (1:10)^4


p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y1)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y2)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y3)) + geom_point()
p4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y4)) + geom_point()

# Create a simple grid
p <- plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, align = 'hv')

# Default font size and position
p + draw_figure_label(label = "Figure 1")
```

I would like to put a label for each figure:

(a) Figure 1
(b) Figure 2
(c) Figure 3
(d) Figure 4

However, I would like the labels to be at the bottom for each figure. It's possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `draw_figure_label` is for drawing a single label on the whole grid, not for drawing labels on each plot. You would be far better adding a caption to each plot to get the same effect:

```r
p <- Map(function(a, b) {
  a + 
    labs(caption = b) + 
    theme(plot.caption.position = 'panel',
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, face = 2,
                                      margin = margin(10, 0, 30, 0)))
  }, 
  a = list(p1, p2, p3, p4),
  b = list('(a) Figure 1', '(b) Figure 2', '(c) Figure 3', '(d) Figure 4'))
```

Now recreate your grid:

```
plot_grid(p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]], p[[4]], align = 'hv')
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent @Allan Cameron, is it possible to remove the bold font?

Comment: @VeltonSousa yes - just remove `face = 2,`

Comment: Also is it possible to share the x and y value of both graphs, @Allan Cameron ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that @VeltonSousa